# How to use a dynamic data list in Matlab GUIDE listbox

Tags: matlab, user-interface, listbox

I am using the listbox item in the GUIDE for a pre-defined data list (strings), according to which I get the 'value' and take some actions. Problem is that this list is composed now as a static list set before compilation and running the program. Now my need is changed and has to deal with a dynamic list that its content received during run time. This means the listbox gets its content during run time and not before compilation.

Can this be done ?    How ?

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this, here shown in response to a button click. The important property is the `String` property of the listbox:

```
f = figure();
lb = uicontrol(f, ...
    'Style', 'listbox', 'String', {'a', 'b', 'c'}, ...
    'Units', 'normalized', 'Position', [.1 .2 .8 .7] ...
);
b = uicontrol( f, ...
    'String', 'Change list items', ...
    'Callback', @(h,e) mycallback(lb), ...
    'Units', 'normalized', 'Position', [.1 .1 .8 .09] ...
);

function mycallback(lb)
    lb.String = {'1','2','3','4','5'};
end
```

Comment: The issue is that what you are suggesting in:  lb.String = {'1','2','3','4','5'}; is also a pre-defined string.  My need is that the string content ( i.e '1','2','3','4','5' ) is read in runtime from some external text file.

Comment: The issue is that what you are suggesting in:  lb.String = {'1','2','3','4','5'}; is also a pre-defined string.  My need is that the string content ( i.e '1','2','3','4','5' ) is read in run time from some external text file. Trying to follow your idea and get into lb.String something from a variable that contains data from a textscan (FileID, %s) command, did not work

Comment: I guess that I need more information about the structure of your text file to answer this. However, one guess is to use `d = textscan(fid, '%s')` and then `lb.String = d{1}`. You should edit your question since your problem seems to be how to read your textfile and hot to prepare the data to be used as a String value for a listbox-`uicontrol`.